# Force parentView to refresh view after navigation controller pops out a child view

Tags: ios

I have secondViewController that can display content in both landscape and portrait view. The MainViewController (parent of secondViewController) can only display content in landscape mode.

When SecondView is in portrait mode and is pop out, the view the MainViewController (which is supposed to display content in landscape mode only) displays content in portrait. It does not refresh to landscape mode.

Is there a way to force MainViewController to refresh the content?

On the MainViewController's viewWillAppear method, I have added setNeedsDisplay and layoutSubviews, etc.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

but it is not reloading the view. I also tried the navigation controller's delegate method - willShowViewController but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if you remove the view and add it back it works

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){        
    NSLog(@"force to landscape mode ");
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:view];        
}
```

You can also use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation  but it the rotation does not work on the navigation controller

```
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/-2.0)];
        //[self.navigationController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/-2.0)];
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0)];
        //[self.navigationController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/-2.0)];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by not letting he user "go back" to the other view unless the app was in the proper orientation (in this case Landscape). What you can do is provide your own "Back" button, and if the view is in Portrait, pop an alert that says please rotate to Landscape first (or better yet animate a small view in from the bottom or top of the screen). Or just hide or disable the back button in portrait (I hid the button).

Its a terrible UI choice to let the user go back, and see the view in landscape while the phone is in portrait mode in any case.

Comment: Adding and removing the view also works. Transformation has some problem with navigationController for some reason. See my answer below.

Comment: So, the user is in portrait, you do your trick, they go back, and they see a view that is rotated 90 degrees and they cannot read it. So they say, "Oh Sh*t", and they move their phone to landscape. Well, if you're happy with this fine. To me this is a horrible solution to your problem, but as they say, YMMV.

Comment: The secondView supports different orientation which is useful when view resources such as pdf. User can change the orientation of secondView if they need to. but I understand what you mean.